# Overlaying the screen with a black rectangle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'd like to, when my iPhone app first loads up, overlay the entire screen with a black rectangle temporarily.  It would cover everything beneath it, so that everything on the screen would be black for a moment.

Anyone know how to write the code to do this?  It would help if you could specify how to remove the rectangle after an allotted time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do what you want with that, assuming you rectangle is an image :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_rectangle.png"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 480.f);
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_YOUR_TIME_
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerFinished:)
                                   userInfo:imgView
                                    repeats:NO];
    [imgView release];
}

- (void)timerFinished:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[timer userInfo];
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  The code works, though I get the following error when I run it: `GDB:Program received signal: ”SIGABRT“`. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Maybe are you trying to release the imgView too many time... Don't know, check where is exactly your crash.

Comment: That was actually it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean splash screen? You can use this tutorial for this.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/03/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-3-splash-screen/

and btw Apple doesn't recommend using splash screen in Human Interface Guidelines

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a client who is adamant about having this splash screen.  Hopefully Apple doesn't mind!